# Upgrade MacTex using tlmgr

Tags: mactex, updating

A while ago I installed MacTex Basic via [Homebrew Cask](http://caskroom.io/), which installed it in `/usr/local/texlive/2014basic` and also set a whole bunch of symlinks in `/Library`, `~/Library` and `/usr`.

After not using TeX for a while I did an update today using `sudo tlmgr update --self --all`, and it updated a whole lot of packages. I found out, that ever since the follow-up MacTex 2015 distribution came out and obviously the update command tried to upgrade my 2014 one. But after that I ran into an [issue](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/545) that could not clearly be solved, without reinstalling the whole thing.

So my question is: is `tlmgr` actually supposed to do distribution upgrades? As MacTex installs into a directory that has the year in its name, one should suppose not. But the update command does so anyway.

What would have been the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Are you sure it updated?  `tlmgr` doesn't update across years, and once the current year is available you should have received a message that the repository contained the wrong year.  (Independent of this, it's always better to avoid other packaging systems like Homebrew/MacPorts when it comes to installing TeX.)

Comment: I went through [this tutorial](https://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html) after the problem appeared, and the [script](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh) did not really update a lot, so I figured that most of the packages were already the latest version due to the tlmgr update before.

Comment: As that page warns, this is not the recommended route. Most of us who use MacTeX just download a [new image](https://tug.org/mactex/downloading.html) every year and then update it using TeXLive Utility (which is a frontend for `tlmgr` that comes with MacTeX).  Yes, it's a big download, but it's completely hassle free.

Comment: So we are not supposed to use `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` anymore once there is a new distribution version out? I am not afraid of big downloads, but if there is a package manager available, I was actually happy to use it, just like using npm, rvm, pip, etc…

Comment: There's no problem using the command line version of `tlmgr` if you prefer (although TeX Live Utility is really nice to use.) But you shouldn't use  Homebrew to manage the installation itself in the first place, just use the supplied `.pkg` file + `tlmgr` to update packages over the year.

Comment: Note that by default `tlmgr update --self --all` will not even attempt to update to a new distribution of TeX Live. Moreover, the system is configured to support multiple versions of TL being installed simultaneously so you can switch between them. MacTeX provides some slick GUI interface to all this in the form of a Preference Pane or something, but it is just as easy to configure on a GNU/Linux box at the command line. And `tlmgr` is ***the*** package manager for TeX Live.  It is the equivalent of `cpan` or `pip`, except that it can do rather more than `cpan`, at least.

Comment: I still dont feel like I got the point. If `tlmgr` is **the** package manager for TeX Live, and its purpose is to upgrade packages, and if TeX Live is a TeX typesetting distribution consisting of a bunch of packages, why am I not supposed to use it to upgrade all of them, thus the distribution? It seemed like it actually did so, but the upgrade system seems to be buggy somehow.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problems as @mcnesium. I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to *update* my several-years-old MacTeX. I'm currently downloading the 2017 release; but once that's done, there's no clear answer to what my ‘next step’ is. (`brew cask reinstall mactex`? `brew cask uninstall mactex`, and run whatever GUI installer this thing is shipping to me? Freakin' just `find / -depth -name "latex" -type d -exec rm -rf "{}" \;`? `/=`